# how marge each value from the same array onto each key

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have this array and I can't figure out how to dissect it and get it to built onto itself.

I have compiled my array to what I think might be the easiest to keep track of:

```
Array
(
    [domain.com] => Array
        (
            [dev] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /var/www/config/
                    [ini] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => db
                            [1] => common
                        )

                )

            [theme] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /var/ww/themes/
                    [ini] => theme
                )

        )

)
```

My whole thing is that I want to make a helper class to parse ini files. So I have through a couple of methods been able to build my array like above.

My end goal is have something like this `parse_ini_file($ini[$domain][$nick][path] . $ini[$domain][$nick][ini] . ".ini", true)`

where $nick is either `'dev'` or `'theme'` its just a way for me to distinguish paths and ini that belong together.

I have tried to do a `foreach` loop through each key value pair but I'm stuck on the fact that one of my values holds an array.

```
foreach (self::$ini[$domain] as $k => $v) {
    //if (self::$ini[$domina][$nick]['path'][$k] === self::$ini[$domain][$nick]['ini'][$k])
        foreach (self::$ini[$domain][$k] as $i => $l) {

            foreach ($l as $m => $n)
                //if (!is_array($i)) {

                   // (strlen($i) - 1 === '/' ? $i : $i . '/');
                    echo $n;
                    //self::$built = parse_ini_file($i . $j, true);
                //}
            }
}
```

It may seem like a mess, but i didn't bother with making meaningful variable names until I am able to make a solid code block. But In my attempt I have done a `foreach` loop through the `$domain` array to extract each `$nick` from there I thought doing another `foreach` to then break it down to get the `path` and `ini` key => values to then built the parse ini file function. But like I said, one of my `ini` key's holds an array so I'm not sure how to loop through that while still being able to parse an ini file and not overwriting the holder variable `$built`

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You've got the right idea with `is_array` in your commented out code.  How do you want the final result to look in the case of the single file vs. multiple files?  Is `$built` supposed to contain an array of output in the second case?

Comment: $built holds the parsed ini array, something like `$build = parse_ini_file(path.ini, true)` where the path is concatenated to the ini values. so `parse_ini_file(/var/www/config/common.ini, true)` then `parse_ini_file(/var/www/config/db.ini, true)` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first go and read about recursion. Just type the word into Google or even Wikipedia, you'll get the idea. Or just look for array_merge and array_merge_recursive at http://php.net, that's what you need. But first read about recursion anyway, you should know such basic things if you are going to write code further.